# ¿Para qué sirve bind en javascript?

Tags: javascript

He encontrado dos respuestas al respecto en este sitio:

- [¿Para que funciona .bind(this) en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/89720/para-que-funciona-bindthis-en-javascript)
- [¿ Cuál es el objetivo de usar bind(this) en un método en JS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40917/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-objetivo-de-usar-bindthis-en-un-m%C3%A9todo-en-js?rq=1)

El problema que veo en estas respuestas es que me parece que están muy centradas en el caso de uso espefíco del ejemplo concreto en el que aparecen. Y además me parecen que no son aptas para personas que cómo yo están empezando (al fin y al cabo uno no empieza a programar directamente con React) Por otra parte si tiramos de [una buena documentación técnica como podría ser la de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) me encuentro que me parece todo demasiado técnico y abstracto.
La información que he buscado en Internet creo que es poco clara en el sentido de que no explica **qué problema soluciona bind**.
Así que me pregunto si no habrá una explicación super simple que además use un ejemplo tipo "Hello World" para poder entenderlo mejor.

En la documentación de mozilla que menciono dice:

> El método bind() crea una nueva función, que cuando es llamada, asigna
> a su operador  this el valor entregado, con una secuencia de
> argumentos dados precediendo a cualquiera entregados cuando la función
> es llamada.
>
> El valor de this es ignorado cuando la función es llamada con el
> operador new.

Miremos esta explicación por partes...

> El método bind() crea una nueva función, que cuando es llamada,
> asigna a su operador  this el valor entregado,

Ni me queda claro que es this en relación a bind ni sé quién entrega qué a quién, pero sigamos...

> con una secuencia de
> argumentos dados precediendo a cualquiera entregados cuando la función
> es llamada.

No sé a qué se refiere con "entregados" ¿Quién entrega qué a quién?
Y por último:

> El valor de this es ignorado cuando la función es llamada con el
> operador new.

Sin entender que es `this` en esta peli, además me meten esto de `new`. ¿Por qué el señor `this` es ignorado? (Con lo que me ha costado aprenderlo llegados a este punto)

Comment: Es una pregunta demasiado extensa, limitala porfavor a una sola pregunta o haz varias preguntas pequeñas, porque tal como lo pones debemos explicar como 5 o 6 temas en una sola pregunta.

Comment: Pues es que la documentación que citas es lo más clara que se puede ser. Tal vez no lo más coloquial pero eso es "lo que es". Creo que la confusión real que tienes está en qué es `this`, por qué el `this` de la función en la que se usa `bind` queda asignado al valor que entregas cuando usas bind (porque no lo usas sin parámetros), y que los parámetros del llamado a la función en la que haces `bind` siempre comienzan por unos ya predefinidos, seguidos por otros que tú defines. Todo eso es claro pero no lo quieres revisar en los ejemplos de las preguntas, revisaste el ejemplo de MDN?

Comment: Basicamente para poder entender `bind` debes poder entender primero `this`, si no entiendes `this` no vas a poder entender `bind`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bind` sirve para el transporte de contextos de un entorno a otro, o bueno, tecnicamente yo lo defino y lo entiendo así, pero como nos dice nuestro queridisimo amigo mozilla en su documentación y como ya haz colocado en la pregunta:

> El método bind() crea una nueva función, que cuando es llamada, asigna
> a su operador this el valor entregado, con una secuencia de argumentos
> dados precediendo a cualquiera entregados cuando la función es
> llamada.
>
> El valor de this es ignorado cuando la función es llamada con el
> operador new.

Por lo que es enrealidad una nueva copia del contexto original, sin embargo antes de proceder a complicarnos mas es mejor intentar entender que es `this`:

**Que es this?**

`this` es una palabra reservada que hace referencia al contexto actual del objeto, en terminos mas sencillos y mas especificos hace referencia a **la instancia de una clase o al cuerpo de un objeto**, en este caso solo puede ser usado con objetos que tengan `cuerpo` y que deriven de un `prototipo`, normalmente objetos `compuestos` o `complejos` como lo pueden ser las `clases`, las `funciones` y los `metodos`.

**NOTA:** Podria haberme referido a cualquier cosa que sea considerado un bloque, donde un `bloque` se define como un espacio delimitado entre llaves:

```
{

}
```

Sin embargo si tomamos esta definicion de que `this` hace referencia a los `bloques`, esta definicion seria erronea, puesto que por ejemplo los `bucles`, `condicionales`, y `objetos` propios de javascript pese a poder ser delimitados entre bloques **NO** tienen contexto, es decir, `this` sera `undefined` para cada uno de ellos, con lo cual nos quedamos con una definicion que aplicara solo a `objetos compuestos` y que ademas no se traten de tipos considerados como `primitivos`.

> Si tratamos de usar `this` dentro de algo como un ciclo o un
> condicional `this` hará referencia al objeto superglobal `window` (si
> estos se encuentran en el `scope global`), de lo contrario `this` hara
> referencia al primer objeto compuesto mas cercano, como lo puede ser
> una `funcion`, una `clase`, etc.

Si aun no ha quedado claro, vamos a ver ejemplos de `this`:

```js
//Formato de clase ES6
class miClase{

  //this referencia a todo este espacio

  constructor(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    console.log(this);
  }
  
  //Hasta el final
  
}

//Formato de clase ES5
function miClase2(x, y){
  
  //this referencia a todo este espacio
  
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  console.log(this);
  
  //Hasta el final
  
}

//Error causado con intencion.
const miClase3 = (x, y) => {
  
  //ERROR this esta indefinido

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  console.log(this);
  
}


const clase1 = new miClase(2, 3);
const clase2 = new miClase2(6, 2);
const clase3 = new miClase3();
```

En la ultima parte del codigo vemos como aparece un error, y es que hay que tener en cuenta que apartir de `ES6` existe algo llamado funciones flecha, las cuales **NO** poseen contexto por lo cual al tratar de invocar `this` dentro de una funcion flecha econtrariamos que `this` es `undefined`.

Esto es una particularidad de las funciones flecha que es bueno que tengas en cuenta, precisamente por esto genere el error.

**Para que sirve bind y porque tiene sentido que exista?**

Es mas frecuente el uso de bind en frameworks como lo son `Angular`, `Vue` o `React` ya que al ser manejados por `clases` o `componentes` tienden a usar el paradigma orientado a objetos **POO**, paradigma en el cual puede llegarse a perder mucho el contexto si no lo usamos adecuadamente.

Ahora bien, se que este va a ser un ejemplo un poco dificil de entender, pero... que pasaria si yo tuviese unos metodos o funciones generales que quiero tener aisladas en una clase general o archivo aparte las cuales seran posteriormente importadas en un archivo para poder ser usadas como si fueran nativamente parte de los metodos del componente?

pues resulta que si lo intentas...

**SE PIERDE EL CONTEXTO**

`this` ya no haria referencia al mismo `this` de la otra `clase` o `funcion` lo que podria generar problemas que en un principio podrias pensar que son un poco extraños como por ejemplo encontrarias que al intentar usar ese metodo `this` seria `undefined`.

Y ojo... creo que hacer lo susodicho en este ejemplo puede ser considerado una muy mala practica ya que por ejemplo en el caso de angular para eso existen los `providers` u otras alternativas.

Sin embargo vamos a obviar este hecho y concentremonos en este turbio ejemplo:

```
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { getToast } from "../../global_modules/globalFunctions";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clase-ej',
  templateUrl: './claseEj.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./claseEj.page.scss'],
})

export class ClaseEj implements OnInit {

  public getToast: (str: string) => any;

  constructor(private toastController: ToastController) {
     //Si no usamos bind se pierde el contexto y el metodo falla al invocarse
     this.getToast = getToast.bind(this);
  }

}
```

Donde el archivo `globalFunctions.ts` contiene:

```
export async function getToast(data){
  const toast = await this.toastController.create({
    message: data,
    duration: 2000
  });

  return await toast.present();
}
```

Como vemos en el segundo archivo se esta usando `this`, este `this` es el `this` original de la funcion `getToast` el cual solo hace alusion al codigo dentro de llaves `{}`, sin embargo como bien sabemos esta funcion no conteiene ninguna propiedad `toastController` asociada con `this`:

```
await this.toastController  //NO EXISTE!!
```

por ende solo queda una opcion...

Que el `this` al que nos queremos referir sea al `this` de la clase del otro archivo.

Pero entones como hacemos para crear una copia rapida de este metodo y que ademas este configurada para utilizar el `this` de la clase y no el `this` de la funcion?

`bind` es nuestra respuesta:

```
constructor(private toastController: ToastController) {
     this.getToast = getToast.bind(this);
}
```

De esta manera la funcion ya no usara su propio contexto, si no que usara el contexto que le hayamos pasado, que en este caso al tratarse de la propia clase podra encontrar la propiedad que definimos anteriormente en el constructor:

```
constructor(private toastController: ToastController) { }
```

**bind** creo que no es usado realmente mucho... ya que se deberian evitar los problemas de contexto en lo maximo, sin embargo para casos donde tengas problemas de contexto `bind` es bastante útil.

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta, muy bien elaborada!

Comment: @Triby gracias, tu respuesta esta excelente tambien `Triby` :D

Comment: +1 Y si fuera posible +2 (voté hace 20min, recién pude poner un comentario xd), por la explicación detallada ¡Buena respuesta!

Comment: Todas las respuestas acá son muy útiles.

Answer (score 5):

Tratando de explicarlo de forma sencilla, `this` se refiere al contexto de ejecución, generalmente, `window` o algún otro factor, como un evento. Entonces, aunque dentro de una función declares propiedades y métodos, `this` puede tomar diferentes valores:

```js
let func = function() {
    this.log1 = function() {
        console.log(this);
    };
    this.log2 = () => {
        // La función no tiene contexto propio, por tanto, this = window
        console.log(this);
    }
    return {
        log1: this.log1,
        log2: this.log2
    }
};

let a = func();
a.log1(); // Objeto
a.log2(); // Window, porque las funciones flecha toman this desde el contexto donde se definen

// Probando con eventos
document.querySelector('#test1').addEventListener('click', a.log1); // Botón
document.querySelector('#test2').addEventListener('click', a.log2); // Window
document.querySelector('#test3').addEventListener('click', a.log1.bind(a)); // Objeto
```

```html
<button id="test1">Prueba 1</test>
<button id="test2">Prueba 2</test>
<button id="test3">Prueba Bind</test>
```

Cuando creas la instancia de una clase, debes anteponer `new` y no puedes usar `.bind()` porque **el constructor** siempre usará internamente `this` para referirse a la instancia.

```js
class Foo {
    // No necesitas "this.", ni "var, let o const" para asignar métodos y propiedades
    texto = 'Algo';
    constructor(texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }
    // Puedes declarar métodos con nombreMetodo() {}
    // O nombreMetodo = function() {}
    log1() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    log2 = () => {
        // La clase sí tiene contexto propio, this = instancia de clase
        console.log(this);
    }
}

let foo = new Foo('Nuevo valor');

// Ambos métodos devuelven la instancia de clase
foo.log1(); // Instancia de la clase
foo.log2(); // Instancia de la clase

// Probando con eventos
document.querySelector('#test1').addEventListener('click', foo.log1); // Botón
document.querySelector('#test2').addEventListener('click', foo.log2); // Instancia
document.querySelector('#test3').addEventListener('click', foo.log1.bind(foo)); // Instancia

// Probando con intervalo
setTimeout(foo.log1, 200); // Window
setTimeout(foo.log1.bind(foo), 500); // Instancia
```

```html
<button id="test1">Prueba 1</button>
<button id="test2">Prueba 2</button>
<button id="test3">Prueba Bind</button>
```

Por defecto, todas las funciones se ejecutan bajo `window` o la función/clase donde se definieron, a menos que sean llamadas en otro contexto, como un evento, donde será necesario enlazar lo que quieras que se use como `this`. Y puede tratarse de cualquier evento: click, load, change, input, mouseenter, etc.

También los intervalos `setTimeout()` y `setInterval()` generan nuevos contextos.

### ¿Cuándo usar `.bind()`?

Es sencillo, cuando el método o función deban ejecutarse en un contexto diferente, generalmente desencadenado por otros factores. El problema principal radica en identificar esos otros contextos.

De acuerdo al ejemplo de clases, puedes evitar el uso de `.bind()` declarando los métodos como funciones flecha.

**Importante:** Te recomiendo leer sobre las [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) para saber porqué `this` siempre tendrá el contexto donde fueron creadas y no puedes usar `.bind()`.

Comment: +1 Y si fuera posible +2, por la explicación detallada ¡Buena respuesta!

Comment: Buena respuesta +1. Ha sido muy útil.