# problema con el ámbito de función, no lee el parámetro this

Tags: javascript, nodejs, callback

construí un par de funciones

```
async callback(ra) {
        // try {
            ra = JSON.parse(ra)
            if (ra.status===true){
                if (fun.empty(ra.data.pd)===false){
                    console.log(ra, 'GTI-00393', new Date())
                    this.updategt_c({pa : ra.data.pd, event : a.event, con_gbl : nuevo.con_gbl, token_wss_user : a.token_wss_user, app : a.app}, this.callback)
                } else {
                    console.log('terminado')
                }
                
            } else {
                console.log(ra, 'GTI-00400', new Date())
            }
        // } catch (e) {
        //  console.log(e, 'error de forma callback')           
        // }
    }
async updategt_c (a, b, c) {
    //funcion de almacenamiento
}
```

leugo ejecute la funcione

```
this.updategt_c({pa : pa[0], event : a.event, con_gbl : nuevo.con_gbl, token_wss_user : a.token_wss_user, app : a.app}, this.callback)
```

la primera ejecución funciona bien, luego para su segunda vuelta me dice que "updategt_c" no tiene propiedades por ser indefinida.

porfavor alguna conjetura del por que y como solucionarlo.

Comment: Te recomiendo pasar por [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/433169/54039), donde se habla del _"misterioso `this`"_, probablemente las respuestas te ayuden a entender lo que está pasando y tal vez puedas solucionarlo con `bind()`, pero depende de cómo ejecutas la _"segunda vuelta"_.

Comment: claro excelente men, enseñar a pescar, suceden esas ocasiones y supongo también te ha sucedido, que vasta con un ejemplo y ya, tema de tiempos supongo, premura, tardanza, la abuela se muere, en fin elije una. de todas todas gracias.